# Postfix Relay Based on Sender Recepient

Tags: email, postfix, relay, recipient

What is the best practice when one has to implement this sort of ruleset in Postfix?

- Email sent from local `domain1.com`, `domain2.com` to `example.com`,
  `example1.com` ought to be relayed to `smtp.external.com`.
- Email sent to everyone else `@example.com` and `example1.com` ought to be
  relayed locally.

I know there is a way to do a relay filtering recipient address using `transport_maps`, but I do not know how to filter depending on the sender address too.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way (although not quite clean in my opinion), matching it with the `header_checks` parameter. For example:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/my_relays
```

Now in `/etc/postfix/my_relays`:

```
/^From:.*asender\@domain1\.com/  smtp1:[host1.example.com]
/^From:.*anothersender\@domain2\.com/  smtp2:[host2.example.com]
```

The `smtp1` and `smtp2` actions are only needed if you need to authenticate on the `host1.example.com` or `host2.example.com` servers by password, otherwise replacing them with the `smtp` keyword would be enough.

If you need to authenticate against those servers, you need to define what is `smtp1` and `smtp2` in your `master.cf` file:

```
smtp1    unix  -       -       -       -       10       smtp
    -o smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/smtp1.relay
smtp2    unix  -       -       -       -       10       smtp
    -o smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/smtp2.relay
```

As a last step, your `smtp[12].relay` files have to include the authentication parameters to connect to those hosts (I remark this is only needed if you need authentication).

```
[hostX.example.com]   userX:passwordX
```

Comment: This command is perfect to filter mail senders, but I want to filter both senders and receivers at the same time. With a certain incoming mail and outgoing mail, filter using an external relay.